# Redshift :Sum of distinct values over partition by

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

How do i add the the distinct marks alone of a student id in student table in Redshift?

In oracle this works,

`SELECT SUM(distinct marks) OVER (PARTITION BY studentid) FROM student;`

But this doesnt work in Redshift ! I want to solve this without joins with SELECT statement alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to either use a `JOIN` or a correlated query when window functions are not available.

Correlated query(Only selects)

```
SELECT t.* ,
       (SELECT sum(distinct marks) FROM student s 
        WHERE s.studentid = t.studentid) as stud_sum
FROM student t
```

Answer (score -2):

Window functions are famous & influential in Redshift.

Since Redshift DB is a fork of Postgres, most of the Windows functions supported in Postgres 8.x are flexible to use.

for the give SQL, you could write something

```
SELECT studentid, SUM(distinct marks) 
  OVER (PARTITION BY studentid) FROM student;
```

SQL should work in Redshift.  Here is the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html) for all Window function support:

Comment: This does not work. Currently redshift window functions don't support `DISTINCT`, only `ALL` or `expression`, as you can see in the documentation you provided a link to.